# Popup menu is not opened

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I got the following files in my Chrome extension project.

```
|--dist
    |--background.js
    |--content.js
    |--popup.js
    |--popup.html
    |--manifest.json
    |--images
        |--get_started16.png
        |--get_started32.png
        |--get_started48.png
        |--get_started128.png
```

`background.js`, `content.js` and `popup.js` only contains `console.log('hello')`.

#### manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "test",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/get_started16.png",
            "32": "images/get_started32.png",
            "48": "images/get_started48.png",
            "128": "images/get_started128.png"
        }
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

#### popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      button {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        outline: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

No errors loading the files (loading the extension as unpacked files). When the extension icon is clicked it opens the default menu with

- Remove from home
- Hide in chrome menu
- Manage extensions
- Inspect popup

etc...not the `popup.html`, However the `content script` and `background script` logging `hello` to their consoles. Clicking on `Inspect popup` does nothing.

I'm using (on Arch linux),

```
Chrome: Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Chromium: Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit)
```

Popup is not working in both browsers. I tried changing file permissions as below

```
chmod -R 777 dist/
```

I loaded [getting started tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) project files. The popup in that is working fine. What as I missing here?

Comment: A page_action means you need to enable it manually on tabs where you want it by using chrome.pageAction.show (see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) and example extensions inside). Depending on the workflow you may want to switch to [browser_action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction).

Comment: @wOxxOm I actually changed that. Lools like reloading the extension are not just enough. Better to remove and reload the extension.